# Append an array into Flutter Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `List` in Flutter, and I want to add the name field of the objects inside as a list into a collection called `requests`
`List selectedAllergies = [];`
[image]

However, when I do this, I get this error message:
`E/flutter ( 4031): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'Allergies'`

```
List selectedAllergies = [
    Allergies(id: 1, name: "Milk"),
    Allergies(id: 2, name: "Peanuts"),
    Allergies(id: 3, name: "Tree Nuts"),
    Allergies(id: 4, name: "Eggs"),
    Allergies(id: 5, name: "Soy"),
    Allergies(id: 6, name: "Wheat"),
    Allergies(id: 7, name: "Shellfish"),
    Allergies(id: 8, name: "Snake"),
  ];
```

```
class Allergies {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Allergies({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });
}
```

Is it possible to append only the "name" field of the `selectedAllergies` list into a document in the collection of `requests`?

Comment: Could you give more details to the contents of `selectedAllergies`? It seems like you are trying to add the objects directly to Firestore.

Comment: Alright, I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't allow adding dart objects directly. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) for a list of supported data types in Firetore.

Instead, as you suggested, we can just add the names of the allergies. The following code illustrates how to get a list of the names.

```dart
  List allergyNames = selectedAllergies.map((e) => e.name).toList();
```

Then, you can add `allergyNames` to your Firestore document instead.